# Zend Framework: Re-use WHERE clause returned from Zend_Db_Select::getPart()

Tags: zend-framework, select, where-clause, zend-db-select

I have a SELECT object which contains a WHERE.

I can return the WHERE using `getPart(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE)`, this returns something like this:

```
array
    0 => string "(clienttype = 'agent')"
    1 => string "AND (nextpayment < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY))"
```

This array seems pretty useless as I cannot do this with it

```
$client->update(array("paymentstatus" => "lapsed"), $where);
```

Or even put it into another SELECT object. Is there a way of getting a more useful representation of the WHERE statement from the SELECT object?

Thanks

***EDIT***

The best I have come up with so far is

```
$where = new Zend_Db_Expr(implode(" ", $select->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first choice, `$client->update(...)` would work, *if* getParts omitted the 'AND' from the second part of the where clause.

I'm pretty sure your only choice is to:

1. use your second option (probably safest depending on how complex the where clauses are) -or-
2. iterate through the $where returned and remove the leading 'AND', 'OR' that may exist.

Comment: +1 Thanks Darryl. I was afraid that someone would say that. I cannot believe that there isn't a more elegant solution to this.