# How to reuse array from Zend_Db_Select::getPart('where')

Tags: select, zend-framework, zend-db

I see a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366749/zend-framework-re-use-where-clause-returned-from-zend-db-selectgetpart), but it's 4-year-old. Is there a better way now to re-use the array obtained from `getPart('where')`?

`getPath('where')` returns an array of individual `WHERE` clause segments like below (example).

```
[0] => (`e`.`type` = 'bleh')
[1] => (AND `e`.`name` = 'blah')
```

I can do some string operations to clean it up the second segment and re-add to `Zend_Db_Select`, but it seems really hacky.